# Move date in letter of class moderncv

Tags: moderncv

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman, num]{isodate} % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\hfill}{}{}{}% Sender address flush-left
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\raggedleft}{\raggedright}{}{}

% Sender address \raggedright
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
%\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\bfseries}
\name{{Jon}}{Doe}
%\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{Jone Doe street 12}{9999 jon}{jon}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+11~(111)~1111}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{jondoe@gmail.com}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
%\date{January 01, 1984}
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
 \date{Jtown, \today}

\opening{\textbf{Bewerbung: }\\[0.5cm]\textbf{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
%\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}         
 % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value of paragraph spacing
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} %create minipage
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.



\makeletterclosing
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

I want to move the date on `moderncv` cover letter and have it **after** the recipient address and **before** the subject and on the right hand side.

How do I do it? I have attached the MWE.

[image]

Comment: Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWYyN.png or even lower such as in https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ9HY.png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be careful, it seems you are using an old version of `moderncv`.  In the current version of `moderncv` 2.0.0 your used `makelettertitle` has been renamed to `makeletterhead`.

To move the date down you have to add the following patch to your code (please see that I use the patch(es) for the current version!):

```
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}{\hfill}{\par\raggedleft}{}{} % move date down
```

With the complete code

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{black}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman, num]{isodate} 


% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
% \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox <================= already loaded by moderncv
%\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}{\hfill}{}{}{}% Sender address flush-left <======================= makelettertitle
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}{\raggedleft}{\raggedright}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}{\hfill}{\par\raggedleft}{}{} % move date down

% personal data
\name{{Jon}}{Doe}
%\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{Jone Doe street 12}{9999 jon}{jon}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+11~(111)~1111}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{jondoe@gmail.com}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\newlength{\currentparskip}


\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
%\date{January 01, 1984}
\date{Jtown, \today}
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}

\opening{\textbf{Bewerbung: }\\[0.5cm]\textbf{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
%\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}         
 % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value of paragraph spacing
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} %create minipage
\setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class 
aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus 
et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna 
libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, 
tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci 
lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

\makeletterclosing
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting letter]

I recommend to update to the current version of class `moderncv`!

If you insist in using the old version try the following patch instead:

```
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\hfill}{}{}{}% Sender address flush-left 
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\raggedleft}{\raggedright}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\hfill}{\par\raggedleft}{}{} % <============ move date down
```

I can not test this because I have only the current version of `moderncv` installed ...

Comment: What if you don't want the sender's name on the left, but on the right? No combination I've tried aligns it correctly.

Comment: @LittleLulatsch Can you please ask a new question? Do not forget to add an short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642771/how-can-i-make-the-cover-letter-from-moderncv-din5008-compliant?noredirect=1#comment1602022_642771